# Precise ip localization in cities

Tags: ip-geolocation

I live in city X, but when i try to get my location via ip all the "find location by ip" websites point to city Y. Some ads "Hang tonight with girls in city X" they precisely know my location. How this is possible? Exists some kind of data, a database with ips which those ads site have?

Comment: It's funny because these ads *never* get my city right (I live in a small town)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as precise location from an IP... the quality of any such service never reaches 100%... as you write there are several different databases out there - each with some very good and rather weak spots... some databases are updates regularly, some aren't etc.

*Those ads use databases which just happen to have their weak spots somewhere where you don't live...*

I have never come across any such service that told my city correctly (although it is not small)... they are off by 20-400 miles sometimes even claiming that I am in a very small city far away...

Mostly you can tell the country correctly... although even that can be fooled by proxy/VPN/anonymizer...

For some insight see:

- http://www.private.org.il/IP2geo.html
- http://ipaddressextensions.codeplex.com/
- http://software77.net/geo-ip/
- http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/get-geographical-location-geolocation.html

A rather special and different case is this:

One rather precise way to tell the location is when you use a device (usually mobile phone)... these have several sources available (like tower locations, like GPS)... another point are the databases Google and Apple build by using anonymized from phones... they basically aggregate data regarding tower, GPS and WLAN HotSpot/access points reachable... this way they can (with a small margin of error) tell from the WLAN data (like MAC address) the location...

Comment: The ads work fine, and they give me the correct position. I need that database, or something similar, but only for a country. From where those website procure the db, they pay for it, or exist a free db?

Comment: @Nogard As I said: the ads work fine for your location/IP but NOT for ALL locations/IPs... if you really want that specific database just dissect the Flash/JavaScript (it could be coded as AJAX or similar) they use and/or eMail the ad provider about which database they are using

Comment: I think tower locations are named HLRs (Home Location Registers), and i try to dissect that script, which basically it is all i need. Thanks.